# CSS - Keep transformed :after element on target

Tags: html, css

I've got an issue with menu styling.

Menu looks like this:
[image]

And each element is styled as follows:

```
.gallery-navi-element {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: height .8s ease;
}
.gallery-navi-element:hover:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    /* top: 50%; */
    transform: translate(-50%,0%);
    top: 40px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 25px 0 25px;
    border-color: rgb(74, 125, 51) transparent transparent transparent;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

In this way i can achieve such effect:
[image]

Still i'm having serious issues making this triangle stay there after a click. Creating jQuery handlers adding classes seems not to work at all since the new class overwrites navi buttons. Have tried playing with `:target` but without luck. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a7zs3z6o/

Comment: Could we also see some HTML?

Comment: Will try to come up with a fiddle in a moment @WillHamic

Comment: @WillHamic https://jsfiddle.net/a7zs3z6o/

Comment: Weirdly this works in IE 11 but not chrome.

Comment: @WillHamic You mean adding :target works in IE? I've only checked it in Chrome to be honest - edit: checked Microsoft Edge - doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `tabindex` to each `gallery-navi-element` element:

```
<div class="gallery-navi-element" id="gallery-show-wszystkie" tabindex="1">Wszystkie</div>
```

That will allow them to be focused when clicked.

You'll then want to remove the default outline that appears on focused elements, which you can do with:

```
.gallery-navi-element:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrn6830/)

Comment: exactly what i needed - will keep in mind from now on to index elements to be focused, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *changing* the navi links' class, just add a new `.hover` class that has the same styles as `:hover`. Then you won't have a problem with lots of overwriting styles.

You would probably have less trouble doing this if you simplified the CSS to only include the transitioned styles in the hover state/added-class state.

```
.gallery-navi-element:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  top: 30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  /* border-width: 0px 25px 0 25px; */
  border-width: 10px 25px 0 25px;
  border-color: rgb(74, 125, 51) transparent transparent transparent;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
.gallery-navi-element:hover:after,
.gallery-navi-element.hover:after {
  top: 40px;
  border-top-width: 20px;
}
```

*Note that the only reason for the `border-top-width` transition is so that your triangle doesn't cover up the bottom of the Y in the first couple links.*

Example:

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery-navi-element');

for(var i=0,l=navLinks.length;i<l;i++) {
  navLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(var i=0,l=navLinks.length;i<l;i++) {
      navLinks[i].classList.remove('hover');
    }
    this.classList.add('hover');
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.gallery-navi {
  border-radius: 28px;
  width: 950px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgb(74, 125, 51);
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
}
.gallery-navi-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 870px;
}
.gallery-navi-separator {
  width: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 36px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.gallery-navi-element {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: height .8s ease;
}
.gallery-navi-element:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  top: 30px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
/*   border-width: 0px 25px 0 25px; */
  border-width: 10px 25px 0 25px;
  border-color: rgb(74, 125, 51) transparent transparent transparent;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
.gallery-navi-element:hover:after,
.gallery-navi-element.hover:after {
  top: 40px;
  border-top-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-navi">
  <div class="gallery-navi-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-navi-element" id="gallery-show-wszystkie">Wszystkie</div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-separator"></div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-element" id="gallery-show-produkty">Produkty</div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-separator"></div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-element" id="gallery-show-tartak">Tartak</div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-separator"></div>
    <div class="gallery-navi-element" id="gallery-show-sklad">Skład</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, it stays the way i wanted it to but also i need JUST one to be present at time, thank you anyways for very valuable advice!

Comment: @DamianDoman Yes, this was supposed to just be an example. You can make only one show up at a time by modifying the JavaScript a bit. I have updated the snippet above to show you how.